# Same code has vastly different run times on different machines

Tags: c++

If I run this code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>
#include <time.h>
#include <thread>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int start_s = clock();
    char randChar;
    string random;
    random.clear();
    int entry_size = 4;
    int population_size = 500000;
    vector<string> population;
    for (int i = 0; i < population_size; i++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < (unsigned)entry_size; i++) {
            randChar = rand() % 25 + 97;
            random += randChar;
        }
        //cout << random<<endl;
        population.push_back(random);
        random.clear();
    }
    int stop_s = clock();
    cout<< (stop_s - start_s)/(double)(CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
}
```

on this web site: http://cpp.sh/ the running time is around 0.16 seconds
however if I compile and run this on my home machine (i5 4460 16 gb ram, mechanical HDD,visual studio 2017) the running time is around 6.6 seconds which is around 41 times slower, what is causing such a huge speed difference? 
thanks

Comment: maybe debug and release build... but: both for loops are using "i" as incremental variable... maybe something strange happends there

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My psychic powers suggest that you built a **Debug** build on your home machine with Visual Studio. Flip the Solution to a **Release** build and watch the performance go way up.

I just tested this with Visual Studio.  The difference between Debug and Release is 100x with your code.  (8 seconds vs .08 seconds).

It's not that Debug builds are inherently slow. It's just that really tight loops doing math, memory, or anything non-blocking can be highly optimized.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that worked, what is the main purpose of debug then? just to make sure the code works regardless of runtime? because the compile times of both settings seem like the same, or is there a difference with bigger programs

Comment: Release builds are inherently much, much harder to debug.  Entire lines, function calls, and local variables can disappear as a result of code getting optimized. Lines of code get re-ordered too.  Attaching the debugger to a Release build can be an insane experience.  The instruction pointer can jump around sporadically instead of incrementing "line by line", breakpoints can get skipped, variables don't show up in the watch window, etc.  VS 2015 introduced the `-Zo` compiler switch to generate better PDB symbols to make debugging Release easier, but it's still harder that Debug build.

Answer (score 1):

different mechanisms to deal with memory management perhaps? it's hard to pinpoint exactly as there can be quite a lot of assumptions, but there are ways to make your code faster on both ends.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>
#include <time.h>
#include <thread>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int start_s = clock();
    char randChar;
    string random;
```

no need to clear something that's empty.

```
    int entry_size = 4;
    int population_size = 500000;
    vector<string> population;
```

pre-alloc the vector, 500000 is a huge number and the vector would have to do many allocations.

```
    population.resever(population_size);
```

also, pre-alloc the string random, and don't clear it every loop. the amount of memory is small but allocating and unallocating is expensive. instead change the values of the preallocated string dinamically.

```
    random.reserve(entry_size);
    for (int i = 0; i < population_size; i++) {
```

you used 'i' as the keys for the inner and the outer for loops, this looks like a bug, I'm changing the index of the inner loop to j.

```
        for (int j = 0; j < (unsigned)entry_size; j++) {
            randChar = rand() % 25 + 97;
            random[j] = randChar;
        }
        population.push_back(random);
    }
    int stop_s = clock();
    cout<< (stop_s - start_s)/(double)(CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
}
```

This should make your app quite faster.

Answer (score 0):

I think some of this factor will effect:CPU,Operation System,Memory size,I/O speed(not in your situation because your code doesn't have any IO),Memory Cache,Parallelization.